# How can i show error message for a particular command , if bash script terminates due to set -e

Tags: bash, bash-trap

I want to display a error log line for one particular command when its return value is nonzero .
I am using ' set -e ' for terminating if any command returns nonzero value along with ' trap ' for this

```
  #!/bin/bash
    set -e

    log_report() {
        echo "Error on line $1"
    } 

    trap 'log_report $LINENO' ERR

    echo "starting ..."
    first_badcommand
    echo "running"
    second_badcommd
```

OUTPUT:

```
starting ...
/tmp/test1.sh: line 10: first_badcommand: command not found
Error on line 10
```

since i use set -e the script exit and showing my error log for first_badcommand.. itself.
I want to exit with error log for only a particular command giving non zero return code
and for rest of commands giving non zero return code,  exit without error log

Comment: How is that possible? it is expected behavior for the script to exit on first non-zero code. You can't bypass that

Comment: sounds like my question is misleading ..There is no problem if the script exit on first_badcommand. My problem is "Display the Error log only when the second_badcommad returns nonzero return code."  Now the error log  is displaying  for any command fails with a nonzero return code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After clarification, it appears that the requirement is to exit the script if any error happens, but that the commands which are described as "badcommand" in the question, might or might not fail.

In this answer, I am naming the commands simply `first_command` etc, to reflect the fact they might or might not fail.

The `set -e` command, as suggested in the question, will indeed terminate the script if an error occurs, and the `trap ... ERR` installs a handler which will run after an error (and before the script exits where `set -e` has been used).

In this case, you should:

- wait until the trap is required before installing it (it does not need to be done at/near the start of the script)
- disable the trap again when it is no longer required, using `trap - ERR`

so that commands to enable and disable the trap surround the command for which the trap is required.

For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

log_report() {
    echo "Error on line $1"
} 

echo "starting ..."
first_command

trap 'log_report $LINENO' ERR

echo "running"
second_command

trap - ERR

echo "still running"
third_command
```

This will exit if *any* command fails (because of the `set -e` at the top), but the trap will only be run if `second_command` fails.

*(Note also that `set -e` similarly does not need to be applied at the start of the script.  It can be enabled at any point, and disabled again using `set +e`.  But in this example, it appears that the exit-on-error behaviour is required throughout.)*

Comment: ,The alternative method will keep on running even if the first_badcommand fails ryt .. my requirement is exit the script without error log if any error happen . exit the script with error log if second_badcommand happen

Comment: @Pratheesh I think several people have been confused about the requirements. Okay, I will edit the answer again.

Comment: @Pratheesh Edited a couple more times. I *hope* I have understood the requirement now. Please can you check.

Comment: this worked..i think i have misled all  of you ..will edit my question

Answer (score 1):

`set -e` does not stop you from checking the status of a command line you'd otherwise do:

```
if some_command
then
  echo "It succeeded"
else
  echo "It failed. Some message here."
  exit 1
fi
```

Comment: This feels very counter intuitive when reviewing all the various trap related answers on the web. But it does work and I would guess is what most people are actually wanting/needing to improve their scripts.